# How do you get a pyramid app to run on apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am trying to follow the basic tutorial on how to run a pyramid app on apache + mod_wsgi and am having a lot of trouble.

Here is the tutorial I am following:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html

I am doing this tutorial on a centos machine with apache and mod_wsgi already installed.

I think the issue I am having is with the httpd.conf file. I pointed the url http://nodeline.com to the server so I am trying to configure the virtual host so that the pyramid app loads when you visit nodeline.com.

This is what I have in my httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nodeline.com

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=main group=main processes=1 \
           threads=4 \
           python-path=/home/main/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
        WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/main/modwsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi

        <Directory /home/main/modwsgi/env>
          WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The tutorial is weird because it seems like it is teaching you how to set this up on your local machine. It does not say anything about a virtual host in there. Is there something I am missing? Or, maybe someone could just point me in the right direction. I would really appreciate someone's help.

Answer (score 3):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/main/modwsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi
```

should be

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/main/modwsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi
```

try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nodeline.com
        DocumentRoot /home/main/modwsgi/env
        <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=main group=main processes=1 \
           threads=4 \
           python-path=/home/main/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/main/modwsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi

        <Directory /home/main/modwsgi/env>
          WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

$ sudo a2ensite pyramid
$ sudo a2dissite default
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Do not set DocumentRoot to be a parent directory of where your code lives. If you inadvertently leave out WSGIScriptAlias, your code, including any passwords in it can be downloaded. Overriding Directory for / in the VirtualHost is also generally ill advised. You should leave it up to the one at global scope in the default Apache configuration because playing around with that and getting it wrong can also decrease the security of your site.